# thread crashes with SIGSEGV or SIGABRT

Tags: python-3.x, qt, segmentation-fault, crash, qthread

I am writing a python wrapper for rsync (one more ;-) and use Qt to display the output of rsync. I realize that when have verbose output for each file my program crashes with SIGSEGV or SIGABRT. I have done a lot of googling, also here and came across a small sample that worked quit well with QtCore.QThread.sleep(1) and 10 iterations in the thread. But when I increase the loop to 100 and reduce the sleep to 0.1 is also crashes like my project.
Anybody an idea what goes wrong?

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Countdown")

        self.edit_field = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.edit_field.setReadOnly(True)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.start_countdown)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.edit_field)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def start_countdown(self):
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.worker = Worker(self.edit_field)
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.thread.start()
        self.button.setEnabled(False)

    def on_finished(self):
        self.button.setEnabled(True)
        self.thread.quit()


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    finished = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, edit_field):
        super().__init__()
        self.edit_field = edit_field

    def run(self):
        for i in range(1, 100):
            self.edit_field.setText(str(i))
            self.edit_field.update()
            QtCore.QThread.sleep(0.1)
        self.finished.emit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I have seen some other post here with answers about "non-reentrant python code", "only inherit from one QWidget" and so on, but don't see the point here in my sample. The only critical point I see here is the thread is using the reference to the edit-line and accesses it directly. Is that a "non-reentrant code problem" ??

Comment: Yes. As the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#qobject-reentrancy) GUI classes are not reentrant, specifically, UI elements are *not* thread safe and shall never be accessed (and not even created) from threads different than the main one, which is where the QApplication has been created and its loop is running. Besides, your `Worker` doesn't seem to do anything that would really require threading. If you want to call a function that updates the UI in some way at regular intervals, use QTimer, as threading is completely unnecessary for this kind of things.

Comment: 1. Yes, here threading is not necessary but it is only to show the crash.

Comment: 2. in my project with rsync where it is to receive and display some 1000 lines of output from subprocess thru a pipe, the challenge is to really read that very fast, because without threading  and with qsleeep  or QApplication.processEvents() to keep the event-loop alive, I already realized that some lines get lost....

Comment: As said, the crash is because you're attempting to access a non thread safe object. And if you get lines lost is probably because of the same reason. The fact that you add a sleep only delays the problem, but doesn't solve it. Except from calling `invokeMethod()` (which should only be used as last resource) or using Queues with appropriate safe measures, signals are the *only* safe (and simple) way to access UI elements from another thread. If you want to update the UI without crawling the main event loop too much, you could add the lines in a "buffer" and emit a signal every time the buffer »

Comment: » has reached an arbitrary length, or after the last message has been received or at regular intervals. How that can be achieved depends on how your worker is actually implemented, so if you want a more comprehensive answer, please take your time and provide a related [mre] that shows what it actually does.

Comment: thanks for the explanations! I understand, that the worker-tread is not helpful at this point. I will try to put the reading from the subprocess pipe back to the main loop and will try to minimize the code in a way that no line is missed....

Comment: Ok. I suppose you're using subprocess with the `rsync` command, so I'd suggest you to look into [`QProcess`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html): while subprocess Pipes should be thread safe (at least on POSIX, afaik), QProcess can naturally work asynchronously using signals, so you can directly connect its `readyReadStandard...` signals and therefore safely access the pipe directly from any function connected to that signal, within the main thread.